WPF Validation - Conditional based upon the AdornedElementPlaceholder
I have a WPF application where I am using a control template to show a red "X" next to a field that has a validation error.
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
        <TextBlock
            Margin="5,0,0,5"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="X"
            FontSize="24"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Foreground="Red" />
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

Later in the XAML, I am referencing the validation template.
<TextBox
    Width="56"
    Height="27"
    TextAlignment="Right"
    Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationTemplate}">
    <Binding
        Converter="{StaticResource DecimalConverter}"
        Path="Length"
        UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <engine:DecimalValidationRule
                ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"
                FieldName="Length"
                Min="0.000"
                Max="100.000" />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <engine:TextBoxInputBehavior InputMode="DecimalInput" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>

My goal is to not show the error "X" if the adorned element is not enabled IsEnabled=False regardless of the value. I would like to do it in the control template, but if it needs to be done at the TextBox level somehow, that will be acceptable too.
So far, any web searches and experimenting on my own have not produced anything other than syntax errors and unrunnable.

You can disable Validation Template (set it to null) using style triggers.
<TextBox
    Width="56"
    Height="27"
    TextAlignment="Right">
    <Binding
        Converter="{StaticResource DecimalConverter}"
        Path="Length"
        UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <engine:DecimalValidationRule
                ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"
                FieldName="Length"
                Min="0.000"
                Max="100.000" />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <engine:TextBoxInputBehavior InputMode="DecimalInput" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ValidationTemplate}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>

</TextBox>

The template option is also possible. In the "ideal case", you need to look for TemplatedAdorner. But this is an internal class, so you can't set it directly in XAML. You can simply look for Adorner. In general, this is not always reliable. But in each specific case, the layout of the template is known, so I think it is impossible to accidentally stumble upon the wrong Adorner.
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationTemplate">
        <DockPanel>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
            <TextBlock x:Name="xBlock"
                        Margin="5,0,0,5"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Text="X"
                        FontSize="24"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Foreground="Red"
                        />
        </DockPanel>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AdornedElement.IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Adorner}}"
                            Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="xBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

For greater security, you can add a markup extension that will return the TemplatedAdorner Type.
    public class TemplatedAdornerExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public static readonly Type TemplatedAdornerType;
        static TemplatedAdornerExtension()
        {
            Assembly assembly = typeof(Adorner).Assembly;
            TemplatedAdornerType = assembly.GetType("MS.Internal.Controls.TemplatedAdorner")
                ?? throw new Exception("\"MS.Internal.Controls.TemplatedAdorner\" Type not found.");
        }
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => TemplatedAdornerType;
    }

DataTrigger Binding:
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AdornedElement.IsEnabled,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                    AncestorType={local:TemplatedAdorner}}}"
                    Value="False">
        <Setter TargetName="xBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>


thank you for a very thorough answer. I chose to augment my ControlTemplate and it worked fine.  You did mention "For greater security, ..." Where can I find more information on the security aspects you are mentioning? This is a strictly internal application, so I'm not sure how much of a security risk I am facing though.

@Jim
In this case, the "danger" is only if there is some other Adorner between Binding="{Binding {RelativeSource ... AncestorType=Adorner...}" and TemplatedAdorner. That is, such a binding will look for the first ancestor of Adorner. In theory, in the general case, this cannot be ruled out. But in practice, I cannot imagine how this could be necessary for anyone. It would be very difficult to implement even on purpose, even with a great desire.
